# Dissuadere qualcuno "da" o "dal" + infinito?

Tags: verbs, prepositions

Ho avuto il dubbio se, dopo l'espressione "dissuadere qualcuno" e prima di un infinito, si debba usare "da" oppure "dal". Per esempio, quale tra queste è la frase corretta?

> Vorrei dissuadere Pietro ***da*** fare qualcosa di cui dopo potrebbe pentirsi.
>
> Vorrei dissuadere Pietro ***dal*** fare qualcosa di cui dopo potrebbe pentirsi.

Alla [voce "dissuadere" nel vocabolario Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/dissuadere/) ho trovato questa frase:

> spero che ormai si sia dissuaso ***dal*** partire

Posso dedurre che l'opzione corretta è sempre usare "dal" prima di un infinito?

**Aggiornamento:**

Ho trovato un documento su Internet, sembra che sia parte di un libro intitolato *In altre parole* e che faccia parte di una collana o qualcosa di simile chiamata *[Datti una regola](https://www.amazon.it/datti-una-regola-zordan/s?ie=UTF8&page=1&rh=i%3Aaps%2Ck%3Adatti%20una%20regola%20zordan)*, in cui c'è una sezione chiamata "Costruzioni richieste dei più comuni verbi e aggettivi". Là ho trovato per il verbo "dissuadere": ***dissuadere da un proposito; dissuadere dal fare una cosa***.

Comment: Non ho prove a sostegno della tua tesi, ma la prima opzione mi suona storta. Direi che "dal" è la forma corretta.

Comment: Ho trovato un documento online, sembra che sia parte di un libro intitolato *In altre parole* e che faccia parte di una collana o qualcosa di simile chiamata *Datti una regola*, in cui c'è una sezione chiamata "Costruzioni richieste dei più comuni verbi e aggettivi". Là ho trovato per il verbo "dissuadere": ***dissuadere da un proposito; dissuadere dal fare una cosa***.

Comment: Purtroppo posso soltanto vedere il documento nella copia cache di Google: http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:_77of7J9VawJ:http://www.scuolabook.it/Uploaded/rcs_s000fbrinf0088v1a5_preview/rcs_s000fbrinf0088v1a5_preview.pdf%2B%22dissuadere+dal%22+%22dissuadere+da%22&nomo=1&hl=it-ES&ct=clnk.

Comment: @DiegoMartinoia: Il documento che ho trovato sembra confirmare quello che hai detto.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

La frase corretta è la seconda:

*dal fare* usa una preposizione articolata perché è un infinito in funzione di sostantivo.

http://aulalingue.scuola.zanichelli.it/benvenuti/2013/03/07/le-forme-implicite-linfinito-semplice-e-composto/

Comment: Grazie della risposta, ma per me non è così evidente che qui l'infinito abbia funzione di sostantivo. Cioè, perché, per esempio, si dice "obbligare **a** fare qualcosa" e non "obbligare ***al***   fare qualcosa"? Non è un tipo di costruzione simile?

Comment: Bruno, vedi il mio commento alla risposta di Sklivvz.

Answer (score 1):

L'articolo preposto al verbo lo sostantivizza.

Per esempio: confronta "dissi a lei di *fare* qualcosa" con "ogni pomeriggio si poneva la questione *del fare* qualcosa".

Nel tuo esempio, "dissuadere da" vuole un sostantivo e quindi il verbo necessita dell'articolo.

Comment: Ma questo non risolve la giusta obiezione di Charo in un commento a un'altra risposta. Anche “obbligare a” si può costruire con un sostantivo (“la legge obbligava i cittadini maschi al servizio militare”) ma se usato con un verbo all'infinito non richiede l'articolo. E lo stesso vale per altri verbi: “viene punito per le sue colpe”; “viene punito per aver commesso [la tal cosa]” etc.

Comment: Il verbo è comunque sostantivato nei tuoi esempi. L'uso dell'articolo è condizione sufficiente ma non necessaria.

Comment: Sono d'accordo con te, @Sklivvz: (c'è l'articolo) => (il verbo è sostantivato), mentre l'implicazione opposta può non valere. Ma questo sembra contraddire la tua osservazione secondo cui «[un certo verbo] vuole un sostantivo e quindi il verbo [retto dal primo] necessita dell'articolo», che corrisponde a (il verbo è sostantivato) => (c'è l'articolo).